# Salesforce "first parameter of loadScript() and loadStyle() must be an LWC component" workaround

Tags: lightning-web-components

I and several others have been getting the following error when testing custom lightning web components in a scratch org:

> "The first parameter of loadScript() and loadStyle() must be an LWC
> component."

While debugging, it is because `platformResourceLoader.js` (which contains `loadScript()`) first null-checks `cmp.template.host.ownerDocument` where in my case, `ownerDocument` is undefined.
This is a documented Salesforce issue and they provide the following workaround:

> Current work around is to create another wrapper lwc custom component and use the custom component with platformResourceLoader in the wrapper.
>
> e.g --- c-lwc-wrapper --
>
> ```
> <template>
>
> <c-lwc-loader></c-lwc-loader> 
>
> </template>
> ```
>
> where c-lwc-loader uses
>
> ```
> import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';`
> ```

Can someone explain to me in more detail what this means? Am I supposed to create an entirely new LWC and nest my original one inside it? The wording of the sentence and my relative unfamiliarity with HTML/JS are causing quite the headache.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently an issue in LWC where `ownerDocument` has been removed from `host` and we're investigating.

Meanwhile, the workaround is to create the script tag manually:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = ''; // code URL
document.head.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function() {
   // init code
}
```

This will give you similar results.

Comment: Does 'document' in this case refer to the html template? <script> tags are not allowed in salesforce html docs and adding a script dynamically from JS is not working either.

`this.template.createElement('script')` is not a valid function call because SF does not allow templates to include <script>. Or am I misunderstanding your post?

Comment: I think it should work: Locker does support dynamic scripts, as long as it's in JS and not HTML.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHoDQAW

In the link you have the workaround but if I had been you, i would have waiting for Salesforce Devs team's updates